# Bash length of string starting with "#"

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I am writing a script that reads input of color hex-code from user, i.e

## #ffffff

I also need to check length of that string to be equal to 7 (1 hash symbol + 6 digits) and have "#" symbol as 1st character. Here's my code:

```
read color
until [ ${#color} -ge 7 ] && [ ${color:0:1} -eq "#" ]
do
echo "Color code must be 7 characters long and start with '#'!"
read color
done
```

But when I try to, I get an error

```
[: #: integer expression expected
```

It works perfect if string is not starting with hash.

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to do a numeric comparison `-eq`, instead of a string comparison:

```
${color:0:1} -eq "#"
```

should be

```
"${color:0:1}" = "#"
```

instead.

> INTEGER1 -eq INTEGER2 - INTEGER1 is equal to INTEGER2
>
> STRING1 = STRING2 - the strings are equal

(*man test*)

Answer (score 2):

If you only need this to work in `bash`, use regular expression matching:

```
color=
until [[ $color =~ ^\#[[:xdigit:]]{6}$ ]]; do
    IFS= read -r color
done
```

For any POSIX shell, use a `case` statement to allow pattern matching

```
color=
until :; do
     IFS= read -r color
     case $color in
       \#[[:xdigit:]][[:xdigit:]][[:xdigit:]][[:xdigit:]][[:xdigit:]][[:xdigit:]]) break ;;
     esac
done
```

or use the `expr` command:

```
color=
until IFS= read -r color && expr "$color" : "#[[:xdigit:]]\{6\}$"; do
    :
done
```

Comment: Wise thinking with `[[:xdigit:]]`, I might just make one small suggestion, and that would be to add a `$` at the end, otherwise `#FFFFFFOOBAR` would still be accepted.

Comment: Good idea. I've added `^` to the first one as well. (`expr` implicitly anchors the regular expression to the beginning of the string, so it would be optional in the 3rd version.)

Answer (score 0):

[Bash scripts use `=` for string comparison](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-11.html), so your code should be:

```
read color
until [ ${#color} -ge 7 ] && [ ${color:0:1} = "#" ]
do
echo "Color code must be 7 characters long and start with '#'!"
read color
done
```

It's saying `integer expression expected` because `-eq` is for integer comparisons

Comment: String comparison is "=" not "==", `(1) s1 = s2`

Comment: You can use `==`, but you should only use it with `[[`, never with `[`.

Comment: @chepner: Yep, although probably better practice just to stick with `=` for string comparisons with both.

Comment: Also it is always a good practice to quote the string comparison arguments, as otherwise  `${color:0:1} = "#"` might fail with a syntax error for something as simple as `color=" 123"`

Comment: @zeppelin: Sometimes not having variables quoted for (eg. globing) is needed.

Comment: @l'L'l `[` doesn't do globbing. There is almost no reason to leave a parameter expansion unquoted when it is an argument for `[`. (It's a different story altogether for `[[`.)